# Facebook Send Dialog not closing after sending message

Tags: angularjs, facebook

I really have a problem with facebook send dialog.
That's the function that trigger facebook dialog

```
function sendLink() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        link: $scope.generatedLink //this link is generated by the server
    }, function (response) {});
}
```

On this website that i'm working, another developer already implement another facebook app.

Can a problem arise because there are two different app-ids on the site? I can't control the dialog because is not opened by the script. After the message is sent, the dialog it's redirected to facebook.

The dialog works the same even if I initialize the window, or if it is initialized by the other developer app-id.

Any idea it's well received.

I tried to do do any idea that i found here, but none of them worked.

I'm sorry if another question like mine exist, but i started to think that's a facebook bug and i can't solve it.

Comment: What do you mean by _“two different app-ids on the site”_? For example embedding the JS SDK using two different app ids is not even possible (at least if you use the code Facebook provides.) Why even a second app in the first place? If the other developer has already embedded the JS SDK, then you can call `FB.ui` already ...

Comment: Even if i'm not embedding the JS SDK of my app, it's not working. Even if i am using the JS SDK that the other developer embedded it , is not working and not a single error is occured. If i'm simply using that function 'sendLink' without embedding any other thing, it's not working. That dialog it's redirected every time to facebook. Sorry for the stupid questions, but it's the first time i'm trying to implement something from facebook.